# iOS 5 View events order change

Tags: ios, events, view

Has anyone noticed that the order in which view events are fired in iOS 5 has changed? Using a Tab Bar switching from one view to another, the order in iOS 4 was: "viewWillDisappear" and then "viewWillAppear". In iOS 5 they are switched. Is it possible to use iOS 5 but have the previous order of events?

Answer (score 0):

This is true.
Seems that the tab's viewDidLoad now gets called BEFORE the app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

I had the app launch initialising something and the viewDidLoad customising it. IOS 5 messed it up until I made the app init routine leave things alone if they had been setup.

I am guessing that you need to be prepared for this and either make your code check in each place that nothing is being undone or corrupted by the other.